# Have you integrated Mantis and Subversion?

Tags: svn, mantis, scmbug

I do mostly Windows development.  We use [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) and [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for our development but they aren't integrated together, in fact they are on different servers.

I did a little googling about integrating the two together and came across [this post](http://alt-tag.com/blog/archives/2006/11/integrating-mantis-and-subversion/).  It looked interesting.

I was wondering if anyone is doing this or has done this and what your experience has been.  If you've got a different solution, I'd be interested in knowing that too!

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if this works when you have no direct access to the svn repository... still looking for similar questions/answers.

Comment: Yes, it worked great for us (which is why I wrote the post). That company used that solution for several years (and may still be using it for all I know). The key for me was learning about subversion hooks, which can be implemented in any language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've used scmbug for quite some time to link SVN to Bugzilla.  Worked very well until we upgraded to Bugzilla 3.2 recently, which broke the integration.  It takes a little while for the scmbug team to catch up when new releases of the SCM tools come out, which is understandable.

Answer (score 5):

I use Mantis with SVN. Pretty much as that link says, though I put the regexp in the post-commit so it doesn't try to update the bug if the commit message is not relevant, that makes non-bug-updating commits respond slightly faster.

My Mantis install is on a different server too. I use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to [call the php](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=8847) method in Mantis 1.1.6.

Put this in your post-commit.cmd hook (you'll need to download [strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and grab perl.exe and perl510.dll from it, you don't need the rest)

```
c:\tools\perl c:\tools\mantis_urlencode.pl %1 %2  > c:\temp\postcommit_mantis.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 exit /b 0

c:\tools\curl -s -d user=svn -d @c:\temp\postcommit_mantis.txt http://swi-sgi-l-web1.ingrnet.com/mantis/core/checkincurl.php
```

and put this in mantis_urlencode.pl

```
$url = `svnlook log -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;

# check the string contains the matching regexp, 
# quit if it doesn't so we don't waste time contacting the webserver
# this is the g_source_control_regexp value in mantis.

exit 1 if not $url =~ /\b(?:bug|issue|mantis)\s*[#]{0,1}(\d+)\b/i;

$url = $url . "\n" . `svnlook dirs-changed -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;

#urlencode the string
$url =~ s/([^\w\-\.\@])/$1 eq " "?"+":  sprintf("%%%2.2x",ord($1))/eg;

print "log=$url";

exit 0;
```

If you want to migrate from VSS, there are a load of scripts, including one I wrote on [codeplex](http://vss2svn.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx).

It all works well, we use it all the time, and its quick enough not to notice its there. Just type "Fixed Mantis #1234" and it resolves the bug and adds a bugnote to it. The script also adds the directories that were modified to the bugnote too (I tried showing changed files but too many detract from easy understanding)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [Subversion post-commit script](https://gist.github.com/762207) we use. It uses PHP to run the Mantis checkin PHP script as suggested in [this link](http://alt-tag.com/blog/archives/2006/11/integrating-mantis-and-subversion/) in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I came across [scmbug](http://freshmeat.net/projects/scmbug/).  Looks like it will hook up things like Mantis to things like Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

We followed the steps in your link - the only difference is that on Windows you have post-commit.bat instead. If you scroll down someone posts a sample. We modified that so it logs the files changed and who changed them - a fairly easy hack to the batch file. We tried including the diffs at one point - but it was obvious pretty quickly that doing that is a bad idea because of the size of some checkins.

It works really well and I'm really happy - now I have to move all our Sourcesafe stuff across...

Answer (score 0):

I am personally using a private SVN repository on my local development environment using VisualSVN Server and a public Mantis bug tracker. I had to change the checkin.php file a bit to handle calls from a web server (with help of this web page: http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=8847)

I have made a short C# console application to handle this instead of a batch file, so it is more configurable and supports remote or local checkin.php files.

I have posted an article about this on my blog with the source code if you are interested: http://mp4m.org/blog/svn-and-mantis-bug-tracker-integration/

Hope that helps!