# Integrate SVN with Mantis on windows server

Tags: php, svn, iis, mantis

I've already gone through the questions :

[Have you integrated Mantis and Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124650/have-you-integrated-mantis-and-subversion)

[Best practice for integrating Mantis and Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215519/best-practice-for-integrating-mantis-and-subversion)

[Integrating google code SVN repository with MantisBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303596/integrating-google-code-svn-repository-with-mantisbt)

Unfortunately, my problem is not listed anywhere & hence, I'm posting this question.

I'm using the Mantis 1.2.15, initially while setting I was giving wrong SVN binary path and it used to give me Invalid Path error, but once the path & permissions were correct, it didn't gave me any such error.

I installed SilkSvn as the SVN client to be used by Mantis.

Then I added a remote assembla repository and whenever I click on `Import Latest Data` or `Import Everything` I get error on `shell_exec` line :

[image]

I consulted the support & they told me that everyone has been given permission to execute svn.exe and I verified that myself. Also, if there was permission, it would have given error
while I gave it the binary path same as earlier when I gave it the wrong binary location.

Can anyone have encountered this issue ? Can you help on what I can try next ?